# Multiple Duplicate Same Size Media Queries in SCSS Mixins - Is it a Problem?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, scss-mixins

**Note**: This is not a duplicate question please read twice before marking as duplicate, I see similar question on stackoverflow but I can't find my answer there.

I am currently converting my CSS code to SCSS and using mixins for my media queries as below.

```
@mixin for-phone-only {
  @media  screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

```
.app_sidebar {
  background-color: set-color(primary, 900);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 set-color(primary, 100);
  flex: 20%;
  z-index: 1;

  @include mq.for-phone-only {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```
.app_main_block {
  background-color: #1e98d7;
  
  @include mq.for-phone-only {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

While implementing this approach, I noticed that it generates multiple media queries of the same size for each of the selectors, with my understanding there should be one single query for the same size. Although the code works as intended, I wonder if this duplication poses any issues or concerns.

Is it a problem to have multiple duplicate media queries of the same size when using SASS mixins? Are there any performance implications or potential drawbacks to this approach? Should I be concerned about the redundancy, or is it an acceptable practice within SASS?

I would appreciate any insights, best practices, or alternative solutions to optimize my media queries in SASS while avoiding unnecessary repetition.

By the was I read below docs and questions, no proper answer.

[Multiple Media queries issue when using sass @mixin and @content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160426/multiple-media-queries-issue-when-using-sass-mixin-and-content)
https://benfrain.com/inline-or-combined-media-queries-in-sass-fight/
https://medium.com/front-end-developers/the-solution-to-media-queries-in-sass-5493ebe16844#.z9osb8t01

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a problem, as you are using the mixin on different classes. The only other thing I can see if to make the mixin into a class, and just use the class. The easiest thing would to just add flex direction into each class style